# Can't get pygame.Surface.get_at() to work properly

Tags: python, pygame, draw, typeerror, surface

I am trying to retrieve the color I have drawn onto my display using pygame, but I can't seem to get it to work. I took out some irrelevant code for easier reading, but here is what I have.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

blue = (0,0,255)

#sets up screen
setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Connections')

pygame.draw.circle(setDisplay, blue, (20,20), 10, 10)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()

    print pygame.setDisplay.get_at((20,20))
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'get_at' requires a 'pygame.Surface' object but received a 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDisplay`is a variable you created, not an attribute on `pygame`.  Try just `setDisplay.get_at((20,20))`.  I'm not sure why you are even getting at the descriptor, it seems like you should be getting an `AttributeError` on `pygame.setDisplay` before even calling the `get_at` descriptor, but in any case, you should be calling it against your `setDisplay`, not off an attribute of `pygame`.

Comment: That works thank you! However, now it is just returning the color black, since the default screen color is black. However, I drew a blue circle at (20,20). How do I access that color blue??

Comment: Not 100% sure how pygame works in this regard, but as the docs say, the last argument to `pygame.draw.circle` is the width of the border, and if you want the circle filled, you need a 0 border (which is the default).  Try removing the last argument to that function call and see if that gets you what you want.