# how to get the color value of a pixel in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to get the color value of a pixel. I have read something about a function called "pygame.Surface.get_at()". But when I use this function i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
pygame.Surface.get_at(300, 200)
TypeError: descriptor 'get_at' requires a 'pygame.Surface' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: Will this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/24789852/1129313 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- `get_at` requires a tuple `(x, y)` so you should invoke it with:

  ```
  .get_at((300, 200))
  ```
- You should provide the surface for which you want to get the pixel color. Something like this:

  ```
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((150, 50))
  ...
  screen.get_at((300, 200))
  ```